# Angular.js components dynamic templateURL

Tags: angularjs, data-binding, angular-template, angular-components

I am Trying to create dynamic templateUrls with angular component. But i get this error as:

`Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: eProvider <- e`

```
angular
    .module('myApp')
    .component('fieldComponent', {
        templateUrl: function ($element, $attrs) {
           return $attrs.templateUrl || 'some/path/default.html'
        },
        controller:fieldComponentController,
        controllerAs:'vm',
        $routeConfig: [
            {path: '/dashboard', component: 'dashboardApp', name: 'Dashboard', useAsDefault: true}
        ]
    });
```

As files getting minified, its throwing error as above. So where & how to i inject this dependencies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do it by adding /*@ngInject*/ at top as suggested by @Matt Richards.

```
/*@ngInject*/
angular
    .module('myApp')
    .component('fieldComponent', {
        templateUrl: function ($element, $attrs) {
           return $attrs.templateUrl || 'some/path/default.html'
        },
        controller:fieldComponentController,
        controllerAs:'vm',
        $routeConfig: [
            {path: '/dashboard', component: 'dashboardApp', name: 'Dashboard', useAsDefault: true}
        ]
    });
```

But, finally i ended up with `ng-include` rather going towards the dynamic template approach, and saved my time covering unit test case.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that your DI in the fieldComponentController is getting broken by minification.  When the code is minified, your dependencies are getting their names changed to things like 'e', which Angular doesn't know how to handle.

One way to deal with this is by utilizing ng-annotate (https://github.com/olov/ng-annotate) to rewrite those variable names in a minification-safe way.

If you're using a build tool like Webpack to do your bundling and minification, you can simply add the ngAnnotatePlugin to your config and include the string 'ngInject' at the top of your controller definition

```
angular.module("MyMod").controller("MyCtrl", function($scope, $timeout)        
{
"ngInject";
...
});
```

ES2015 Version:

```
export class MyCtrl {
    constructor($scope, $timeout){
        'ngInject';
    }
}
```

Comment: Its fine to inject the services inside controllers, but how to achieve the same for templateurl function?

Comment: Hmmmmm - I'm not sure.  I wonder if you could inject those dependencies in the controller and then dynamically set the template by using a div with an ng-include that dynamically loads the template